# Unable to remove pgadmin3 version 1.18 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, software-installation, postgresql

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have pgadmin3 version 1.18.1, PostgreSQL 9.4 installed.
I am new to pgadmin3.

**I want to upgrade to pgadmin3 1.20.0.**

So I used

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`

Then I had 2 different versions [1.18.q and 1.20.0] of pgadmin3 installed on my machine.
So I tried to remove pgadmin3 using these commands seperately,

`sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove pgadmin3`

also tried,

`sudo apt-get purge pgadmin3
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove pgadmin3`

but this removed the 1.20.0 version and not 1.18.1.

I tried removing the 1.18.1 version by using the same commands then it says that the pgadmin3 is not installed.

What should I do to have pgadmin3 version 1.20.0 installed on my machine?
I want to remove version 1.18.1-2.

[This is the link to the snapshot which shows that I have 2 versions installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGXcw.jpg)

When I do,

`apt-cache show pgadmin3 | grep Version:`

it shows,

`Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg12.4+1
Version: 1.18.1-2`

**EDIT**

Output of,

`apt-cache policy pgadmin3`

is:

```
pgadmin3:
  Installed: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
  Candidate: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.20.0-3.pgdg12.4+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
     1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

The output of command,

`grep -r 'pgadmin3' /usr/share/applications`

is

```
/usr/share/applications/pg-doc-pgadmin-9_3.desktop:Exec="/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/scripts/launchbrowser.sh" file:///opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/pgAdmin3/share/pgadmin3/docs/en_US/index.html
/usr/share/applications/pgadmin3.desktop:Exec=pgadmin3
/usr/share/applications/pgadmin3.desktop:Icon=pgadmin3
/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index:pg-doc-pgadmin-9_3.desktop "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/scripts/launchbrowser.sh" file:///opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/pgAdmin3/share/pgadmin3/docs/en_US/index.html         false
/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index:pgadmin3.desktop   pgadmin3            false
```

**AND**
For:

`# grep -r 'pgadmin3' ~/.local/share/applications`

Output is:

`grep: /root/.local/share/applications: No such file or directory`

For:

`# command -v pgadmin3`

it shows:

`/usr/bin/pgadmin3`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy pgadmin3`

Comment: And the output of `grep -r 'pgadmin3' /usr/share/applications; grep -r 'pgadmin3' ~/.local/share/applications; command -v pgadmin3`

Comment: also this please `grep -r 'pgadmin3' ~/.local/share/applications; command -v pgadmin3`

Comment: Run `grep -r 'pgadmin3' ~/.local/share/applications` as **regular user** and **not as root user**.

Comment: for a regular user , there is no output

Comment: Run `sudo find /home -type f -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -l 'pgAdmin' {} \;`

Comment: `$ sudo find /home -type f -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -l 'pgAdmin' {} \;`

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Comment: correct the sudo warning with `sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo; sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: And run `sudo find /usr/share/applications -type f -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -l 'pgAdmin' {} \;`

Comment: And why do you think, that version `1.18.1` is still installed?

Comment: @VivekS Did u try to purge cummand 'apt-get purge pgadmin3' or 'dpkg --purge pgadmin3'

Comment: @PKumar, Viveks never had both versions installed, the APT package system disallows it for the pgadmin3 package.  The problem was an error in perception about the state of the system.

Answer (score -1):

`pgadmin` version 1.20 is currently installed on your system.

I don't think you've ever had both 1.18 and 1.20 of `pgadmin3` installed at the same time.  The icons on the desktop have little relation to the actual installed versions of the applications.

In the case of the `pgadmin3` package, the Debian APT package management system prevents you from having more than one version installed at the same time.

When you install an application for which multiple versions are available, look at the output of `apt-get install` to see the installed version number.

The output of your `apt-cache show pgadmin3` output shows that you have 3 versions of `pgadmin3` available for installation:

```
$ apt-cache show pgadmin3 | grep Version:
Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg12.4+1
Version: 1.18.1-2
$
```

(The version `1.20.0-3.pgdg12.4+1` is for Ubuntu Precise 12.4. You should probably remove `precise-pgdg` from your software sources.)

I hope the following sections help you understand the steps you've been through and what was actually happening:

## Default Trusty `pgadmin` Installation

This is on Trusty 14.04 with `pgadmin3` 1.18.1-2 installed. Neither `trusty-pgdg` or `precise-pgdg` appear in the software sources.

```
$ apt-cache policy pgadmin3
pgadmin3:
  Installed: 1.18.1-2
  Candidate: 1.18.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
```

Show *installed* versions of `pgadmin3`:

```
$ dpkg-query -W pgadmin3
pgadmin3        1.18.1-2
$
```

Invoke `pgadmin3 -v` to show the *executable* version:

```
$ pgadmin3 -v
pgAdmin III 1.18.1
$
```

## Adding the `trusty-pgdg` repo (contains newer `pgadmin3`)

Now I've created a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list` containing the line:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

And then run `sudo apt-get update`. Looking at the `apt-cache policy` we see now a new version (1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1) from the `trusty-pgdg` repo. Note the line "Candidate:" which shows which version is the best candidate to be installed:

```
$ apt-cache policy pgadmin3
pgadmin3:
  Installed: 1.18.1-2
  Candidate: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
     1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
```

NOTE: Because there is a new "Candidate", either `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt-get install pgadmin3` will install the new version of `pgadmin3`.

## Install `pgadmin3` again to get the most recent version from new repo

Now install `pgadmin3` again, to get version 1.20 (we already have `trusty-pgdg` in our software sources list). `apt-get install` by default attempts to install the latest version, shown by the line "Candidate:" in the policy above:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
[ . . . ]
Preparing to unpack .../pgadmin3_1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pgadmin3 (1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1) over (1.18.1-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../pgadmin3-data_1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking pgadmin3-data (1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1) over (1.18.1-2) ...
[ . . . ]
Setting up pgadmin3-data (1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Setting up pgadmin3 (1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1) ...
[ . . . ]
$
```

And verify the installed version:

```
$ dpkg-query -W pgadmin3
pgadmin3        1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
$

$ pgadmin3 -v
pgAdmin III 1.20.0
$
```

Also shown by `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy pgadmin3
pgadmin3:
  Installed: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
  Candidate: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
$
```

If you try to install again, no action will be taken:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pgadmin3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
```

Comment: Hello, I have added the snapshot which shows both the versions. When I open both, the version numbers are shown 1.18.1 and 1.20.0

Comment: A screen shot of icons doesn't tell anything about the versions. You need to know the versions from the package management system.   Please run this command and put the output in your question: `apt-cache show pgadmin3 | grep Version:`

Comment: This is the output of the command,
apt-cache show pgadmin3 | grep Version:

Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg14.04+1
Version: 1.20.0-3.pgdg12.4+1
Version: 1.18.1-2